# How fast is access to atomic variables in C++

Tags: c++, atomic, c++11

My question is how fast is access to atomic variables in C++ by using the C++0x actomic<> class? What goes down at the cache level. Say if one thread is just reading it, would it need to go down to the RAM or it can just read from the cache of the core in which it is executing? Assume the architecture is x86.

I am especially interested in knowing if a thread is just reading from it, while no other thread is writing at that time, would the penalty would be the same as for reading a normal variable. How atomic variables are accessed. Does each read implicity involves a write as well, as in compare-and-swap? Are atomic variables implemented by using compare-and-swap?

Comment: Depends on hardware. Which do you have in mind? Also, you don't really have much choice. You can hardly decide not to use atomic if you decide it is too slow, and just hope that you don't have any races!

Comment: And how wide is the data? And what alignment?

Comment: Assume the data is an integer that can fit well into the cache line. Actually my question is whether false sharing will affect atomic variables or it is the same if there is false sharing or not. For mormal variables false sharing would slow down ofcourse, and so would for atomic variables, but I want to know if there is penalty even when there is no false sharing.

Comment: Also what do you mean by "if one thread is just reading it"? If you only have one thread reading, you don't need to make it atomic.

Comment: 32 bit integer, properly aligned can be handled with `LOCK` instruction.

Comment: I mean at that instance one thread is reading, later on another one might write to it.

Comment: @Metallic I think you need more details in your Q

Comment: Perhaps related (but *not* the same question): [Overhead of using locks instead of atomic intrinsics](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4296876/1968)

Comment: A thread writing it, must lock/invalidate all other cache lines pointing to the same memory. After the 'writing' is done, all other processors using the same line, must re-fetch the cacheline. Either by snooping from another cache, or from the memory. After the cache line is fetched, it is valid until another processor invalidates it again.

Comment: Christopher, is it for atomic variables too? What goes under the hood, do they use compare-and-swap. If so wouldn't each read also involve write?

Comment: @Christopher: that depends on the memory ordering used. It might be true of the default memory ordering (which is "sequential consistency"), but it might not be true of more relaxed orderings.

Answer (score 4):

If you want raw numbers, Anger Fog's [data listings](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) from his optimization manuals should be of use, also, [intels manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html/) have a few section detailing the latencies for memory read/writes on multicore systems, which should include details on the slow-downs caused by bus locking needed for atomic writes.

Comment: I've read that in new processors they lock the cache, not the whole bus!

Answer (score 3):

The answer is not as simple as you perhaps expect. It depends on exact CPU model, and it depends on circumstances as well. The worst case is when you need to perform read-modify-write operation on a variable and there is a conflict (what exactly is a conflict is again CPU model dependent, but most often it is when another CPU is accessing the same cache line).

See also [.NET or Windows Synchronization Primitives Performance Specifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235934/net-or-windows-synchronization-primitives-performance-specifications/2537064#2537064)

Answer (score 3):

Atomics use special architecture support to get atomicity without forcing all reads/writes to go all the way to main memory.  Basically, each core is allowed to probe the caches of other cores, so they find out about the result of other thread's operations that way.

The exact performance depends on the architecture.  On x86, MANY operations were already atomic to start with, so they are free.  I've seen numbers from anywhere to 10 to 100 cycles, depending on the architecture and operation.  For perspective, any read from main memory is 3000-4000 cycles, so the atomics are all MUCH faster than going straight to memory on nearly all platforms.